# ExpandableListAdapter for complex layout

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I need to display a list of products (from SQLite) with name,price,description. The products are grouped in categories. I take the products from an SQLite table that has all the information inside.
The table is called "preturi" and it has the fields "Categorie", "ProductName", "Price", "Description"

So what I want to obtain is an ExpandableListView like bellow (see the layout further bellow) :

```
"Category one"
   "Product1", 25.22, "FirstProduct"
   "Product2", 21.13, "SecondProduct"
   "Product3", 16.24, "ThirdProduct"
"Category two"
   "Product4", 5.72, "FourthProduct"
   ...
...
```

Until now, I managed to obtain and display a grouped list but only Category/ProductName. I need to be able to display the other two properties of the product (price and description).
How should I change my code in order to send and inflate these 2 extra fields?

So far, I use the following code:

```
list_group.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Category here"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then

```
list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Product name"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPret"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So basically I want to populate the "lblPret" and "lblDescription" labels with data from my SQLiteTable

The layout of the activity (PreturiActivity) where I display the expandableList is:

```
activity_preturi.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ro.mypack.myapppack.myapp.app.PreturiActivity">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity class code is as follows:

```
public class PreturiActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preturi);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp); // getting the listview
    prepareListData(); // preparing list data
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter); // setting list adapter
}

private void prepareListData() {
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
String catego = "";
Integer i = 0;

final SQLiteDatabase db = new myDbHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cy = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT categorie FROM preturi group by categorie", null);
if (cy != null) {
    if (cy.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            catego = cy.getString(cy.getColumnIndex("categorie"));
            listDataHeader.add(catego);
            Cursor cz = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM preturi ", null);
            if (cz != null) {
                if (cz.moveToFirst()) {
                    List<String> continut = new ArrayList<String>();
                    do {
                        catego = cz.getString(cz.getColumnIndex("den_produs"));
                        myprice = cz.getString(cz.getColumnIndex("price"));
                        mydescr = cz.getString(cz.getColumnIndex("description"));
                        continut.add(catego); // here I should be able to add more than just "catego" (product name)
                    } while (cz.moveToNext());
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), continut);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }while (cy.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure I should replace `"HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;"` and `List<String> continut = new ArrayList<String>();` with something else where I can put more information. What would that be and how do I handle it?
(I don't paste here the adapter code unless you need to see it, but it's pretty standard)

The core of the adapter that I use is this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}
TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
TextView txtListChild_pret = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblPret);
txtListChild.setText(childText);
txtListChild_pret.setText(childText);
return convertView;
}
```

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes are required to be done:

1. Instead of preparing `List<String>`, you can prepare a list of objects, e.g. `List<ProductClass>`.
2. You have to define custom adapter for your ExpandableListView.

**Custom adapter:**

Where in getChildView() of your custom adapter, you have to get and set details into your views:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    TextView itemDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemDescr);

    ProductClass objProduct = yourArrayList.get(groupPosition).getItemList().get(childPosition);

    itemName.setText(objProduct.getName());
    itemDescr.setText(objProduct.getDescr());

    return v;

}
```

Check more at: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html

Comment: Can you give me some code? I understand the concept (I thought of it too) but I have some difficulties implementing it

Comment: @user1137313 please read answer carefully and do research around it. Food for thought: You have to define a class with getter/setter methods, prepare an object with name, detail and price and put it inside your ArrayList. Pass this arraylist to your custom adapter where you will have to override getChildView, refer above example.

Comment: Thank you. I use the same kind of approach in the adapter, only I use ArrayList. It's just that the tutorial describes and adapter NOT built from SQLite, so I am researching as we speak, but I was hoping for a little more... I am in a hurry big time :(

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me by putting me on the right track. I solved my issue